# How to complete an entire column (non-consistent) based on previous value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

So let's say I have the followings values:

```
A2=a, A5=b, A6=c, A10=d
```

Basically I want a complete down the previous values as it follows:

```
A2:A4=a,A5=b, A6:A9=c,A10:A99999=d
```

I tried this: I inserted a new column to the right and did something like this: `=IF(A2="",A1,A2)` but this works only for the first 2 instances on the B column since there are more gaps and there are not always the same number of gaps. I'm missing something obviously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this, you almost had it with your own formula.  You just need to use B1 instead of A1.  So B2 would contain:

```
=IF(A2="",B1,A2)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub FillDown()
   Dim rng As Range, r As Range
   Set rng = Range("A2:A99999")

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      For Each r In rng
         v = r.Value
         If v = "" Then r.Value = r.Offset(-1, 0)
      Next r
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: It worked perfectly and i managed to edit it so it can be applied to my concrete case. It looks pretty complicated to make this kind of codes but i'll look into your sugestions.

thank you very much.